# Get the Nth type of variadic template templates?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

How to get the Nth type of variadic template templates? For example

```
template<typename... Args>
class MyClass
{
    Args[0] mA; // This is wrong. How to get the type?

};
```

Comment: Check the std::tuple implementation (using Inheritance mixed with Templates)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use `std::tuple`:

```
#include<tuple>

template<typename... Args>
class MyClass
{
    typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Args...> >::type mA;
};
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want something without using `std::tuple` this works

```
template<std::size_t N, typename T, typename... types>
struct get_Nth_type
{
    using type = typename get_Nth_type<N - 1, types...>::type;
};

template<typename T, typename... types>
struct get_Nth_type<0, T, types...>
{
    using type = T;
};
```

Than

```
template<std::size_t N, typename... Args>
using get = typename get_Nth_type<N, Args...>::type;

template<typename... Args>
class MyClass
{
    get<0, Args...> mA;
};
```