# How to create flexible templates C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am trying to create abstract class which is a template for another classes. Is it possible to create "flexible" `template`?

Several classes will inherit from this one, all of them will have the functions with the same name, but with different arguments. The abstract class is "Interface" of inheritance classes - I will use pointer of this one to manage another.

For example we have two classes: `A` and `B`.
`find` method of `A` class needs only `type1` type, but the same method of `B` class needs `type1` and `type2` types.

This is how I am creating classes that inherit from template:

```
class A : public Repository<int> {
   public void find(int) override; };


class B : public Repository<int, float> {
   public void find(int a, float b) override; };
```

Its all about the part after `public` keyword. I don't want to type `<int, float>` to all classes.

I there any way to overload(?) the  `template<typename type1, typename type2>` and the function?

The code of the abstract class.

```
#ifndef REPOSITORY_HPP
#define REPOSITORY_HPP

#include <string>

//template<typename type1>
template<typename type1, typename type2> 
    class Repository
{
    protected:
        typeSTRING name;

    public:

        virtual void find(type1) = 0;
        //virtual void find(type1, type2) = 0;
};

#endif
```

Comment: this sounds like a case for old fashioned overloading, no need for templates

Comment: @pm100 I have to use templates.

Comment: So you want to write `class A : public Repository` and have `A::find(int)` be detected to deduce that `Repository<int>` should be used?

Comment: @Quentin I can write whole `class A : public Repository<int>`
But I want the program to use only the `Repository::find(type1)`

Comment: " I have to use templates" - why?

Comment: @KKMKK I don't get what you mean by "use only `Repository::find(type1)`". If that's the only function provided by `Repository<type1>`, surely that'd do it.

Comment: Read Andrei Alecsadrescu - Modern C++ Design and Aleksey Gurtovoy - C++ Template Metaprogramming: Concepts, Tools, and Techniques from Boost.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Its a part of my homework.

Comment: @Quentin But in this case I am forced  to write `<int, float> ` after `public` keyword in all classes.

Comment: Coming at it from another way: if you declare `template <class... Args> class Repository`, and in there `virtual void find(Args...) = 0;`, then you'll get the bare minimum for your `A` and `B` classes to compile as-is. Is that what you're looking for, or is something missing?

Comment: @Quentin Yes, but I will be forced to write `: public Repository<Args . . .>`, not just  `: public Repository<Arg>`,

Comment: @KKMKK no, you'd write (for example) `: public Repository<float>` and then you can override `find(float)`. Which is exactly what you did in `A` and `B`.

Comment: @Quentin No, if my template is: `template<typename type1, typename type2>`, I need to write for example ` : public Repository<float, int>` in all classes. I am trying to avoid that. If my class needs only one type, I want to write , for example:  ` : public Repository<float>`.

Comment: @KKMKK that's exactly what `Args...` buys you. It means "zero, one or more parameters". See *parameter pack* and *variadic template*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement the below comment from @KKMKK, this is how you can get an specific type from Args... (from: [get the Nth type of variadic template templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953139/get-the-nth-type-of-variadic-template-templates)):

```
template <typename ... Args>
class Interface
{
  public:
    using FirstType = typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Args...> >::type;

    virtual void add(FirstType) = 0;
    virtual void find(Args... args) = 0;
};

class Impl2 : public Interface<int, float>
{
  public:
    void add(int value) override
    {
      std::cout << "found" << value << std::endl;
    }
    void find(int value, float other_value) override
    {
      std::cout << "found" << value << " " << other_value << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
  Impl2 impl2 {};
  impl2.add(5);
  impl2.find(5, 10.2);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You would need variadic template in base class, i.e

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename ... Args>
class Interface
{
  public:
    virtual void find(Args... args) = 0;
};

class Impl1 : public Interface<int>
{
  public:
    void find(int value) override
    {
      std::cout << "found" << value << std::endl;
    }
};

class Impl2 : public Interface<int, float>
{
  public:
    void find(int value, float other_value) override
    {
      std::cout << "found" << value << " " << other_value << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
  Impl1 impl1 {};
  impl1.find(5);

  Impl2 impl2 {};
  impl2.find(5, 10.2);
}
```

Comment: This solution provides another problem. What if my template has more then one method, for example: `virtual type1 add(type1, type2) `?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are saying, then add that method to your derived implementation with two types. Where that derived implementation can override for `find(type1)` and `add(type1, type2)`.

Comment: @AdvSphere Ok, but how to add in `Interface` method of `Args` type?