# C++: recursively match argument type with class template type

Tags: c++, templates

I am hoping to achieve such type matching function:

```
    MyClass<int, bool> temp;
    temp.print(-1, false);           // works
    temp.print(-1);                  // compile error, too less argument
    temp.print(-1, "string");        // compile error, wrong type
    temp.print(-1, false, 'c');      // compile error, too many arguments
```

Basically, when given template parameter, `MyClass`'s function `print` accepts arguments of exactly the same type, no more, no less.

And this is my current implementation:

```
template<class... ClassType>
class MyClass {
public:
    template<typename... ArgType>
    void print(ArgType... args) {
        matchType<ClassType...>(args...);
    }

private:
    template<typename Type>
    void matchType(Type t) {
        std::cout << "matching " << t << "\n";
        std::cout << "end\n";
    }

    template<typename FirstType, typename... Rest>
    void matchType(FirstType firstArg, Rest... args) {
        std::cout << "matching " << firstArg << "\n";
        matchType<Rest...>(args...);
    }
};
```

But it fails to detect and match type that it compiles well for the code:

```
    MyClass<int, bool> temp;
    temp.print(-1, false);           // works
    temp.print(-1, "string");        // works, shouldn't work
    temp.print(-1, false, 'c');      // works, shouldn't work
```

Can someone explain to me what have I done wrong?

[live code](https://onlinegdb.com/o0ueXz27o)

Comment: What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve? Although the question as asked seems answerable, it doesn't seem to have value beyond learning exercise.

Comment: `"string"` is a `const char*`, which in turn can be converted to both `int` and `bool`.

Comment: @Incomputable The real big problem has been simplified. This code snippet describe my current trouble.

Comment: @super That's true but it doesn't break when too many arguments fed in.

Comment: Why would it break? You have a variadic template function that accepts any number of arguments. The fact that you are explicitly specifying only 2 of them doesn't stop the function from deducing the rest.

Comment: @Koothrappali, you can do SFINAE on the templates of a function, e.g. `template <typename ... Args, typename = compare<std::tuple<ClassType...>, std::tuple<Args...>>`. I still do not think this is a good idea.

Comment: As a counter example, doing `temp.matchType<int>(1,2, "hey", 3.5);` is also perfectly valid. First type is specified. Rest is deduced.

Comment: @super I'm hoping `temp.print<int>(1,2, "hey", 3.5);` to break as well, but currently have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @Incomputable SFINAE is a good idea, could you elaborate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

template<class... ClassType>
class MyClass {
public:
    template<typename... ArgType>
    void print(ArgType... args) = delete;

    void print(ClassType ... args) {
        std::cout << "works\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<int, bool> temp;
    temp.print(-1, false);            // ok

    temp.print(-1);                   // error
    temp.print(-1, "string");         // error
    temp.print(-1, false, 'c');       // error
    temp.print(-1L, false);           // error
}
```

Comment: shouldn't `temp.print(-1, false);` compiles?

Comment: sorry, typo, fixing

Answer (score 1):

To make it work, you have to check at compile time that `ArgType...` and `ClassType...` are the same. This does the job:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template<class... ClassType>
class MyClass {
private:
    template <typename... ArgType, std::size_t... I>
    static constexpr bool check_type_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        return (std::is_same_v<typename std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<ClassType...>>::type,
                               typename std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<ArgType...>>::type> && ...); }

    template <typename... ArgType>
    static constexpr bool check_type() {
        return (sizeof...(ArgType) == sizeof...(ClassType)) &&
                check_type_impl<ArgType...>(std::index_sequence_for<ClassType...>{});
        }

public:
    template<typename... ArgType, class = std::enable_if_t<check_type<ArgType...>()>>
    void print(ArgType... args) {
    }

};

int main()
{
  MyClass<int, bool> temp;
  temp.print(-1, false);           // works
  //temp.print(-1);                  // compile error, too less argument
  //temp.print(-1, "string");        // compile error, wrong type
  //temp.print(-1, false, 'c');      // compile error, too many arguments
};
```

See it [Live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9b289d0e17dfa10).

The member function `check` compares one-by-one the type of `ArgType...` and `ClassType...`. It does that by passing to `check_impl` an [std::index_sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) of indices from 0 to `sizeof...(ClassType)`. `check_impl` returns true if the I-th types are identical. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953139/get-the-nth-type-of-variadic-template-templates) for the use of `std::tuple_element` to extract the type of I-th element of a variadic pack.